# Use a custom formula with arrayformula for distances between two columns of cities in Google Sheets with App Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas, custom-function

I have a custom formula in Google Apps Scripts and Google Sheets that gives the distance between two cities. [EXAMPLE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1irEVri9opqp5v8MraOdBsvNO6NG8CtjBEgnOC7bufrM/edit?usp=sharing)

`=MILEAGE(A2,B2)`

```
function MILEAGE(origin,destination) {
  Utilities.sleep(0);
var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
  .setRegion('US')
  .setOrigin(origin)
  .setDestination(destination)
  .getDirections();

var route = directions.routes[0].legs[0];
var distance = (route.distance.value) * 0.000621371;

return distance
}
```

The formula works great for two cells, but I need it to work like an arrayformula for two rows of cities **for each row independently**. I have weighed the pros and cons of running the script once with an array and returning an array and it is not effective in this application because I do not want the entire range to re-calculate every time one row is added/changed.

The objective is for it to work like this:

`=arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"", MILEAGE(A2:A, B2:B), ""))`

Any suggestions on how to do this, or better ways to accomplish the same goal will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on custom function in the "guides" section? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, as well as the documentation on optimization and using apps scripts with array inputs.

Comment: So, Have you attempted to modify the function as stated in the documentation?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes, it doesn't have documentation relevant to what I am attempting to do. I am not trying to pass a whole range into the function for it to be evaluated as a whole, and it does not discuss passing multiple arrays into the same function. I also tried nested functions and some other methods, but I simply don't have the JS knowledge to make it work. Hence why I asked for help. However, thank you for the tag info page link, it was helpful.

Comment: Then it would have been better to ask a specific question about each or any of those issues like, `How to passing multiple arrays into the same function?` Project/goal oriented questions helps nobody but yourself. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/

Comment: @TheMaster thank you for the feedback, I will try to improve my questions going forward to make them more applicable to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that, when you use pass a range in a custom function, it doesn't pass the range, but the values.

What I recommend is that you use a trigger specifically `onEdit` so when you are editing a specific cell, it only recalculates that row. I also made it so that if you remove or add multiple location, they update the corresponding rows.

#### Script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var row = range.getRow();
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var lastRow = range.getLastRow();

  for(var i = 0; i <= lastRow - row; i++)
    if (row + i > 1 && (column == 1 || column == 2) && sheet.getName() == "Sheet1") {
      var origin = sheet.getRange(row + i, 1).getValue();
      var destination = sheet.getRange(row + i, 2).getValue();

      if(origin && destination)
        sheet.getRange(row + i, 3).setValue(calculateMileage(origin, destination));
      else 
        sheet.getRange(row + i, 3).clearContent();
    };
}

function calculateMileage(origin, destination) {
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setRegion('US')
    .setOrigin(origin)
    .setDestination(destination)
    .getDirections();

  var route = directions.routes[0];
  if (route) {
    var legs = route.legs[0];
    var distance = (legs.distance.value) * 0.000621371;

    return distance;
  }
  else {
    return "no route found"
  }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- I found a cell that returns error due to invalid location or no route found so I tried catching it.
- If a row doesn't have a value on either cell, it will delete remove the distance column.

Comment: NaziA, I really like your solution but I can't figure out how to implement it into my sheets. Can you please clarify a little on its use and how you arranged it work as showing in your output GIF?

Comment: @Kevin, have you tried straightly copying the code above to your script? There should be no setups needed. Delete the contents of your sheet first then copy and save the script. Then add the contents back. `onEdit` was used so you need an edit on the row on columns A and B to trigger the function. There should be no additional setup needed. I believe a simple trigger is used and not an installed one.

Comment: And also code makes sure that the edit sheet is named Sheet1. If it is not Sheet1, then it wont trigger. The edits should be on rows 2 and below, and it should be on columns A and B of Sheet1. Any edits someplace else will not trigger the function

Comment: @ASyntuBU That worked. And I see where I can customize this in the script. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To make this function array compatible,

- Check if it's a array  and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)  it's elements
- If it's not a array, directly pass the elements
- [Cache service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache) may also be used to avoid making repeated calls to maps.

```
/**
 * @param {string} origin
 * @param {string} destination
 */
function MILEAGE_(origin, destination) {
  try {
    const sCache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
    const key = `${origin}_${destination}`;
    const cached = sCache.get(key);
    if (cached) return Number(cached);
    Utilities.sleep(1);
    const directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
      .setRegion('US')
      .setOrigin(origin)
      .setDestination(destination)
      .getDirections();
    const route = directions.routes[0].legs[0];
    const distance = route.distance.value * 0.000621371;
    sCache.put(key, String(distance), 21600);
    return distance;
  } catch {
    return '#ERROR';
  }
}

/**
 * @param {A1:D1} arr
 * @param {A1} param1
 * @param {C1} param2
 * @customfunction
 */
const mileage = (...arr) =>
  Array.isArray(arr[0]) ? arr[0].map(e => MILEAGE_(...e)) : MILEAGE_(...arr);
```

#### Usage:

```
=MILEAGE("origin","destination")
=MILEAGE(A1,B1)
=MILEAGE(A1:B100)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! While this does work to an extent, it doesn't seem to be solving some of the main issues. An issue I have come across is that if there is an error in one of the rows, it breaks the whole column. And if I update one row, it recalculates the whole column as well. It also doesn't let me use an open-ended range without throwing errors on the empty rows. This is something I specified in the original question.

Comment: @Kevin Are you using the latest script? Most of the issues you've said(like open ended ranges, empty rows) have already been dealt with. If you're still having issues with errors, I would add a `try{}catch{}` block.

Comment: Yes, [see example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1irEVri9opqp5v8MraOdBsvNO6NG8CtjBEgnOC7bufrM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @kevin I only see `#ERROR` on errored rows only in your sheet. However, see if the latest script using try catch solves your issues. Recalculation is inevitable in a custom function, but most of the script is bypassed using the cache.

Comment: If you're only looking to hide `#ERROR` just change `#ERROR` in  the function above to `''`.  Alternatively, `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(MILEAGE(A:B)="#ERROR",,MILEAGE(A:B)))`. If you  really want to avoid all recalculations at all cost, @Nazi's answer would better suit you.

Comment: I’m trying to get yours to work until NaziA gives some more instruction. Your script does correctly omit rows that are blank, but is there a way to have it omit rows that are a blatant error? I put a deliberate error on B25 and it seems to break the whole column. What do you suggest? (This would be run on a compilation of many peoples data, so errors/typos have to be considered)

Comment: the expected row count that this would be run on is between 500-2000.

Comment: @Kevin Just for clarification the latest script( modified yesterday) using `try` and `catch` would've avoided that as well

Comment: Hey can you invite me to a chat? I dont have the reputation.

Comment: @Kevin I invited. You may also join  the official chat room. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.